Django asks to migrate an unknown app: authtoken
Recently I got this message on running the server.
You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): authtoken.
The git branch is unchanged, no recent commit contains any authtoken relations.
rest_framework.authtoken is part of INSTALLED_APPS since a long time, but as said, no recent changes relate to it.
How can I discover what is causing this message in order to get rid of it?

pls add settings.py

The answer is easy:
rest_framework.authtoken is an application with models and its own migrations.
You can find the reason here:
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/master/rest_framework/authtoken/migrations
These are the 4 db migrations you need to do before you can use rest_framework.authtoken.
To get rid of this - you need to run the standard management command:
python manage.py migrate

This is specifically mentioned in the documentation for rest_framework.authtoken
here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication
p.s. If you made migrations for this model a long time ago, it could be,  that after rest_framework update there appeared a new migration: 0004_alter_tokenproxy_options.py
You can simply check it to run:
python manage.py showmigrations

more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-showmigrations

As said, this has already been done a long time ago. Why does this migration request come out of the blue now?

probably, you are updatet rest_framework or Django, because in version 4.2 was changed migration check behaviour (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/releases/4.2/#miscellaneous)
